# How to remove unwanted text from html

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text that is appearing inside the `body` tag of my website because of some malformed integration. Just as a quick fix I would like to remove it from the front end. This is the text:

```
","author":"ccc","publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"ccc ccc ccc","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://ccc//cc/ccc//.png"}}}
```

I don't have access to the sourcecode, but would like to quickly get rid of this text using a script tag on the front end. Obviously the body tag contains a lot of other nodes so I'm not sure how to cut out just the text and keep the other divs inside the body tag in their place?

```
<body>
","author":"ccc","publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"ccc ccc ccc","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://ccc//cc/ccc//.png"}}}
<div class="dontremoveme">
<div>
<div class="dontremoveme">
<div>
<body>
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant part of the page source?

Comment: Can share all of your code. and see if you can do an .replace() in javascript

Comment: have updated to show it, also how is that a duplicate??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the markup, I guess you can target `document.body.firstChild` element:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var node = document.body.firstChild;
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

```html
\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
<div class="dontremoveme">foo</div>
<div class="dontremoveme">bar</div>
```

It is possible to use a loop instead and remove all nodes from the beginning until you find a *valid* node, such as a wrapper div.

Comment: how i did it was i typed 'document.body.children' into chrome dev tools and found which nodes i wanted to remove.. then i removed them:

var node2 = document.body.children[1];
var node3 = document.body.children[1].previousSibling;
var node4 = document.body.children[1].nextSibling;

node2.remove();
node3.remove();
node4.remove();

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of your body like this :

In jQuery:

```
var inputString = $('body').html();
inputString = inputString.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '$1\n');
$('body').html(inputString);
```

In Javascript

```
var inputString = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
inputString = inputString.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '$1\n');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.html(inputString);
```

Comment: ok thanks! how about something more complex like the updated above??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
// declaration :
clearMe = function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3)
        node.textContent = node.textContent.trim();
    else
        for (let n in node.childNodes)
            clearMe(n);
}
// call:
clearMe(document.body);
```

My function is recursive and it does not force the reinterpretation of the html code, for example with the following code all events are lost

```
node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML; // <- every EventListener or node.onEvent are lost
```